# É possível mudar definitivamente o estilo de uma classe CSS usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```js
$("#mudarcss").click(function(){
  $(".teste").css("background-color", "blue");
});

$("#adicionardiv").click(function(){
 $("#conteudo").append("<div class='teste'>Minha Div 2</div>");
});
```

```css
.teste {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo">
  <div class="teste">Minha Div 1</div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="mudarcss">Mudar css</button>
<button id="adicionardiv">Adicionar Div 2</button>
```

Perceba que, no resultado gerado pelo código acima, uma `div` com fundo **vermelho** é criada. Após clicar no botão <kbd>Mudar css</kbd> a `div` passa a ter o fundo **azul**. Até então tudo está saindo como o imaginado, mas ao clicar no botão <kbd>Adicionar Div 2</kbd>, então uma nova `div` é adicionada com o fundo **vermelho**.

Entendo que a nova `div` não existia ainda quando o fundo da primeira foi alterado, e pelo que parece o JavaScript só altera os atributos dos elementos que já existiam naquele momento no contexto do DOM, e não altera em nada os atributos CSS (que estão dentro das tags `<style>`) presentes na página.

Existe alguma forma de fazer com que o estilo seja definitivamente mudado para os elementos existentes e para os que passarão a existir via JavaScript, ou terei que recorrer a outra alternativa?

Comment: Em vez de mudar o CSS, não é mais fácil criar os dois estilos e o botão mudar o estado de uma variável que informa qual é o estilo atual? Mudar CSS pelo JS não é algo legal nesse caso, basta mudar o `className` do elemento e os novos já criar o novo `className`

Comment: Boa @GabrielKatakura ... Faz muito mais sentido! rsrsrs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os modelos não são criados dinamicamente, eles somente alteram entre si, pode fazer dessa maneira:

```js
var cssAtual = 'red';

$("#mudarcss").click(function(){
  cssAtual = 'blue';
  $(".teste").attr('class', cssAtual);
});

$("#adicionardiv").click(function(){
  $("#conteudo").append("<div class='" + cssAtual + "'>Minha Div 2</div>");
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo">
  <div class="teste red">Minha Div 1</div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="mudarcss">Mudar css</button>
<button id="adicionardiv">Adicionar Div 2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

A única forma de mudar o estilo de um elemento é sobrescrevendo ou adicionando uma nova regra numa tag style, como demonstrado abaixo:

```js
var flag = false; // flag para controle

$("#mudarcss").click(function() {

  if (!flag) {
    $("<style type='text/css'> .teste{ background-color:blue;} </style>").appendTo("head");
    flag = true;
    console.log("Estilo adicionado. :)");
  }

});

$("#adicionardiv").click(function() {
  $("#conteudo").append("<div class='teste'>Minha Div 2</div>");
});
```

```css
.teste {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo">
  <div class="teste">Minha Div 1</div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="mudarcss">Mudar css</button>
<button id="adicionardiv">Adicionar Div 2</button>
```

Como mencionado pelo @Matheus uma alternativa seria criar uma classe e apenas adicionar no elemento que você quer que contenha o estilo.

Comment: Boa! E o bom é que ele só sobrescreve a propriedade alterada... https://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/tcqo8dsz/

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Mas para cada mudança será criado um novo elemento de estilo, isso não poderia trazer algum tipo de sobrecarga?

Comment: Pq não criar duas classes CSS e uma variavel global no JS que manipula as duas classes?

Comment: Basta adicionar uma flag =D

Comment: @Matheus acredito que realmente essa seja a melhor opção... Vlw pela dica! Mas a resposta do Laerte tem algo que eu nem imaginava ser possível fazer, rsrsrs...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Manipulando o DOM você consegue fazer qualquer coisa. :P